# Can i use/call resultset or preparedstatement object created inside curly braces, outside of that braces?

Tags: java, jdbc

It is said that Resultset object or preparedstatemt object is still there unless you close it. So is it possible to call it outside that of curly braces wherein it was created.

Something like

```
  if (output.equals("A")) {

            PreparedStatement pst = connextion.prepareStatement("Query1");

        } else if (output.equals("B")) {
            PreparedStatement pst = connextion.prepareStatement("Query2");}

            pst.setString(1, qty1);
            pst.setInt(2, qty2);
```

If not, is there way to do it so that first i create PST based on certain condition and then use it through a common syntax?

Comment: You can use any object from wherever you want, provided you have a reference to this object. Where you created the object doesn't matter. If you think about it, prepareStatement() creates a PreparedStatement, and you're using it outside of the method (and its curly braces) prepareStatement where it was created, aren't you?

Comment: Of course not, you wouldn't have a reference to that object.

Comment: @JBNizet please delete your wrong comment. references are only accessible within the *scope* they are declared in and *curly braces* are scope limits.

Comment: @TimothyTruckle it's not wrong. Maybe it's just that you don't understand it. What do you think is wrong in my comment? You're confusing objects with references, and references with variables.

Comment: @TimothyTruckle please don't ask people to delete valid information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Nope** you can't instead you can use :

1. **Declare** your PreparedStatement out side the block by null
2. **Use** it (inisitialize your PreparedStatement inside your if or else block)

your code should look like this

```
PreparedStatement pst = null;//declaration outside your if block

if (output.equals("A")) {
   pst = connextion.prepareStatement("Query1");//initialization inside your if block 
} else if (output.equals("B")) {
    pst = connextion.prepareStatement("Query2");//or initialization inside your else
}

pst.setString(1, qty1);
pst.setInt(2, qty2);
```

Comment: thanx buddy, but object is still not dead unlsess i close it? So why i can't access it?

Comment: what did you mean **object is still not dead unlsess i close it**?

Comment: @Roker closing a statement or a ResultSet doesn't "kill" the object. The object still exists. closing it changes its state, and thus the behavior of its methods. For example, getting the next row from the resultset will work fine before you close it, but will throw an exception after you've closed it. That has nothing to do with variable scopes or curly braces.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively to YCF_Ls answer you can simply select the query string *before* creating the `PreparedStatement`:

```
String query = "DefaultQuery"; // you have no "final" else,
                               // therefore you could pass the if/else cascade
                               // without initializing the query reference.
                               // so we have to give a default value here.
if (output.equals("A")) {
 query=  "Query1";
} else if (output.equals("B")) {
 query=  "Query2";
}
PreparedStatement pst  = connextion.prepareStatement(query);
pst.setString(1, qty1);
pst.setInt(2, qty2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just tweak your business logic. Below is my recommendation.

```
String SQL = null;
if (output.equals("A")) {
   SQL = "Query1";    
} else if (output.equals("B")) {
   SQL = "Query2";
}
PreparedStatement pst = connextion.prepareStatement(SQL);
pst.setString(1, qty1);
pst.setInt(2, qty2);
```